# index appears the list of 5 indices closest

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a method or function that from an index (or the name of a movie) appears the list of 5 indices (list of 5 films) closest

My DataFrame :

```
movie_title  movieId   Action  Adventure  Fantasy  Sci-Fi Thriller
Avatar         1        1.0      1.0        1.0     1.0     0.0
Spectre        2        1.0      1.0        0.0     0.0      1  
John Carter    3        1.0      1.0        0.0     1.0     0.0
```

Put the DataFrame as a matrix :

```
df_matrix = userGenreTable.as_matrix(columns=userGenreTable.columns[2:])
```

calculating the distance between two vectors :

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

for i in range(len(df_matrix)):
    for j in range(len(df_matrix)):
        print(distance.euclidean(df_matrix[i,:], df_matrix[j,:]))
```

I do not see how to calculate the five indexes of the nearest vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .loc like this.

```
# Build the array
arr = np.array([[distance.euclidean(df_matrix .loc[i,'Action':'Thriller'],
                                df_matrix .loc[j,'Action':'Thriller']) for j in range(len(df))]\
                                for i in range (len(df))])

# Find the min distance
i,j = np.unravel_index(arr.argmin(), arr.shape)

print([i,j]) # prints the slice location for the minimum euclidean distance.
```

It's tricky to reference dataframe columns as indexes, but an update to .loc lets us scan through a 'range' of them. Hope that helps!